# File Upload in Android WebView

Tags: file-upload, android-webview

I was wondering, is there any way to simulate the **File Upload** using **`javascript`** interface provided by android webview?

Currently `Android KitKat` doesn't support file upload and i can not wait for next update.

Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

This [similar stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882331/html-file-input-in-android-webview-android-4-4-kitkat) demonstrates that it can be done, and links to a Cordova plugin to achieve what you want.  From looking at that plugin source code you should be able to see how to do it ;)