# memory card files and folder listing in phonegap(cordova)

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new to phonegap(cordova)v3.5.0.

I am creating an app for Android and IOS where the users can upload files from mobile memory card to server. Default input type file is not working with phonegap. So, I have tried with fileapi and not able to get it done.

I want to show files and folder list from memory card on clicking on the upload button and the user should be able to select the file to upload.

Please help me to fix this. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

input file is broken on android 4.4, 4.4.1 and 4.4.2, but it should work on other android versions

You can read more about this, and get info about a plugin to use on a question I opened a year ago

[HTML file input in android webview (android 4.4, kitkat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882331/html-file-input-in-android-webview-android-4-4-kitkat)