# Uploading files using the Kik Browser

Tags: kik

I'm trying to build a file-sharing app for Kik but the Kik messenger browser seems to disable a simple html file input element like this:

```
<input type="file" id="input">
```

Why is this not working and is there any other way to upload files from within a Kik tab? I realize that there is this photo API available:

```
kik.photo.get
```

but what about other file types like video, audio etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the "accept" field to the input. iPhone doesn't support uploading arbitrary files because the user interface makes no reference to the file system.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
<input type="file" accept="video/*">
<input type="file" accept="audio/*">
```

#### EDIT

According to the link you're on Android 4.4. Apparently Android 4.4 shipped with a change to the WebView that is causing this broken behaviour.

See this thread: [HTML file input in android webview (android 4.4, kitkat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882331/html-file-input-in-android-webview-android-4-4-kitkat)

Comment: I've tried this but nothing happens when clicking on "Choose file" on my Android device, the button is just not opening any kind of dialog. 

It's a Samsung Galaxy S: http://www.whatsmybrowser.org/b/8UZ6ENB