# Phonegap: Resolving content:// URI obtained from native file chooser

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am using the [Cordova Filechooser plugin](https://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser) to select files from my Android device. The plugin returns a content:// URI (e.g. content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A15756). I am making a call to **resolveLocalFileSystemURI** in order to be able to resolve the content URL and draw the image on a canvas. However for some reason the URI isn't being resolved properly.

E.g. The returned entry's fullPath is */com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A15756*
for the content URI *content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A15756*

Any ideas? My code is as follows:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(_this.target_image, function (fileEntry) {
            var img = new Image();
            alert(fileEntry.fullPath);
            img.src = URL.createObjectURL(fileEntry.fullPath);
            img.onload = function() {
                    combiner_context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                    combiner_context.putImage(0, img.height, _that.editor_img);


            };
        }, function () {
            alert('Could not load selected file. Please try again.');
        });
```

Comment: There is not necessarily a file that you can access. That plugin does not implement a "file chooser", despite its name. It implements a content chooser, using Android's `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. What comes back (your `content://` value) is a `Uri`, that a native Java app would use to get an `InputStream` to read in the chosen content. There is no requirement that a `Uri` be a file that you can access, and the odds of it being a file that you can access decrease with each successive Android OS release.

Comment: I see. The file accessed are from the gallery, which is accessible by my application...Any alternative plugin that you would recommend?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have a recommendation for you.

Comment: Resolved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735864/invoke-native-file-browser-using-phonegap

Answer (score 4):

I was able to convert from a "content://" URI to a "file://" URI using this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-filepath.

After obtaining the "file://" URI, I'm then able to use Cordova's resolveLocalFileSystemURL() function.

Hope this helps.

```
if (fileUri.startsWith("content://")) {
    //We have a native file path (usually returned when a user gets a file from their Android gallery)
    //Let's convert to a fileUri that we can consume properly
    window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(fileUri, function(localFileUri) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL("file://" + localFileUri, function(fileEntry) {/*Do Something*/});
    });
}
```

Comment: i tried and it is working, but i get a SECURITY_ERR if i try to copy or read the File. I want to get the Content of a File from Outlook on Android.