# Android Cordova - Sending local file via API

Tags: android, file, cordova, file-upload

I'm building an Android app using Cordova.

I have a form with `<input type="file" />` in it.

I would like to send an avatar image via `PUT` API method:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'PUT',
  url: my_fancy_api_url,
  data:
    {avatar: url_to_avatar}
  }).done(function(resp){
  ...
```

If I send it via web api form everything works fine, but when I'm trying to send it via Cordova app it doesn't change/gets an error that avatar is not a file etc.

My question is: how to get local file url from file input? If I try `file_input.value` I get `C:/fakepath...`, but if I try `file_input.files[0]` or `file_input.files[0].name` it doesn't work either - how to get this dynamic path properly? What's the correct way of doing it?

All tutorials about cordova's file / filetransfer plugin has already known path to file, but I don't know how to get it properly.

Comment: Are you providing option to thw user to select the image from anywhere in the device to be uploaded? Why cant you use file plugin for this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it correctly - if I click on file input then the file manager appears and I can select files from the device - but after selecting how to get proper value from the file input?

Comment: This link should help you get started - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735864/invoke-native-file-browser-using-phonegap