# <input type="file"> doesn't work in Inappbrowserxwalk. Help me

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, crosswalk

I heard that 'Inappbrowser' doesn't support 'input type="file"' tag when connecting to an external site on Android.
So I found 'inappbrowserxwalk' plugin which supports the 'input file' tag. I have embedded into my website. But, I found that it only triggered 'once'. It doesn't even returned the pictures which I selected.
Is this a bug and can it be solved?

Comment: Please show your code and any debug info you have.

Comment: @Alex using file plugin would be a better option

Comment: @Dan I don't have debug info because I was just translating what my friend said....   But this is what my friend sent me.

Comment: @Dan <cordova plugin install> 

-cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

-cordova plugin add https://github.com/Shoety/cordova-plugin-inappbrowserxwalk

 
<Add index.js file>

    onDeviceReady: function() {

        //app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

        var browser = window.inAppBrowserXwalk.open("http://plugins.krajee.com/file-basic-usage-demo", options);

    },


And then he excuted the 'input file tag' in http://plugins.krajee.com/file-basic-usage-demo which is build by Cordova on Andrioid mobile.

Comment: @Dan And then he excuted the 'input file tag' in http://plugins.krajee.com/file-basic-usage-demo which is build by Cordova on Andrioid mobile.

Comment: @Gandhi I am totally newbie here... Could you let me know more specific information?

Comment: @AlexLee Check out this link which can help  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27166192/html-5-file-input-with-ios-and-android-cordova-phonegap

Comment: @Gandhi Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Alex did it work? Your problem resolved?

Comment: @Gandhi Yes! but I had to use 'iFrame' to make it work..

Comment: @Alex glad it worked.cheers

Comment: @axel-lee What do you mean by "Yes! but I had to use 'iFrame' to make it work? 


The links posted by @Gandhi makes reference to the bug within Cordova App. According to my knowledge uploading a file within Cordova works fine. 

The problem appears when you load an external website with a `input file` and try to upload the file there. 

In this case the behaviour is: First click appears file dialog but choosing file has not effect. Next clicks nothing is happening. Only works again if a full page reload is executed.

So far I do not know a way to solve this.