# how to do mulitpart request from cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have to submit form with an image + some additional form fields (mulitipart form submission request).
I have tried this

```
function upload() {
    var img = document.getElementById('image');
    var imageURI = img.value;
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "photo";
    options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var params = new Object();
    options.params = params;
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, "https://www.example.com/upload.php", win, fail,
        options);
}

function win(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
}
```

html is

```
<input type="file" id="userImage" name="photo">
```

but it is returning error code 1
and image path is fakepat\1089001 
it is also not getting picture name instead a number is showing?
so how do i get image path from input text box?

If i hard code the image (only for testing) in src then request

error code 1
undefined varailbe  image

Remember i have to submit image in base64 url

Comment: Have you checked that your server accepts cross domain requests?

Answer (score 1):

Additional form data would be sent in your params object. Yours is blank now, but you could do

```
options.params.formkey1 = value1;
options.params.formkey2 = value2;
```

As for your second question (and I'd try to keep things limited to one question at a time), you need to pass the path of the file on the device. See the docs for File Transfer.

Finally, you don't need to use base64 to upload the data. I'd avoid that as it is bigger than binary data. Just let FileTransfer push up the binary data. It was built to do so.

Comment: Thanks Raymond: but the main problem is that I am not getting the path correctly

Comment: and how to give image it error also image undefined

Comment: You need the path to the image. If you used the Camera API for example, one option is to get the file uri. That would work.

Comment: you can't get the real path from an input file, and input file is broken in some android version, use the file chooser plugin instead. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882331/html-file-input-in-android-webview-android-4-4-kitkat