# can't open file chooser in WebView Android 4.4.2 using WebChromeClient

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, webviewclient, webchromeclient, android-afilechooser

In my webview by clicking **"Choose File"** button In samsung 7 inch tablet I want to open a File Browser, but I can't open this in ***Android Version 4.4.2***.
So can u plz help me for this?
Here is my Code.

**WebViewDemo.java**

```
package com.example.webviewdemo;

import java.io.File;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.webkit.ConsoleMessage;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WebViewDemo extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    WebView web;

    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent intent) {
        if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
        {
            if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                    : intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show_web_view);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        web = new WebView(this);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/select.html");
        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
        {
            //The undocumented magic method override
            //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here
            // For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                WebViewDemo.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

            }

            // For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser( ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType ) {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                WebViewDemo.this.startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                        FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }

            //For Android 4.1
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                WebViewDemo.this.startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( i, "File Chooser" ), WebViewDemo.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );

            }

        });


        setContentView(web);


    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        }
    }

    //flipscreen not loading again
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

// To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
/*@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
        web.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}*/
}
```

**Inside assets/select.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header">
  <h1>PRODUCT DETAIL</h1>
  </div>

<div data-role="content">
<form method="get" action="">

   <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="name">Open File Chosser And Select File From Camera :</label>
    <input type="file" name="text" id="name" type="image/*" >
    </div>
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="name">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="text" id="name" value="" placeholder="What's Your Name?">
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="search">Looking for anything?</label>
    <input type="search" name="search" id="search" value="" placeholder="Search for content"/>
  </div>

  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="colors"><a href="http://www.androidexample.com/media/webview/webview_browser.html">Open link in webview browser.</a></label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="colors"><a href="http://www.google.com/">Open link in new browser.</a></label>

 </div>

   </div>

</form>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [link](http://androidexample.com/Open_File_Chooser_With_Camera_Option_In_Webview_File_Option/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=128&aaid=148) I hve tried this code. If I open (http://www.androidexample.com/media/webview/details.html) that mentioned in code into device's browser then it works fine. but if i run that code in application then in web view it doesn't work.

Comment: This cant be done in KitKat and is something that tons of developers are frustrated with.

Comment: I got solution from [ this ][1]link. You have to use cordova plugin for this.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882331/html-file-input-in-android-webview-android-4-4-kitkat

Answer (score 2):

This will worked definitely, because i have already tried it...

```
 public class MyWb extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

WebView web;
ProgressBar progressBar;

private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;  
 private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;  

 @Override  
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  
                                    Intent intent) {  
  if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)  
  {  
   if (null == mUploadMessage) return;  
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null  
                    : intent.getData();  
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);  
            mUploadMessage = null;  
  }
  }  

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    web = new WebView(this);  
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/199/index.html");
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()  
    {  
           //The undocumented magic method override  
           //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here  
        // For Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {  

            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
            i.setType("image/*");  
            MyWb.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);  

           }

        // For Android 3.0+
           public void openFileChooser( ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType ) {
           mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
           Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
           i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
           i.setType("*/*");
           MyWb.this.startActivityForResult(
           Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
           FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
           }

        //For Android 4.1
           public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
               mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
               Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
               i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
               i.setType("image/*");  
               MyWb.this.startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( i, "File Chooser" ), MyWb.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );

           }

    });  


    setContentView(web);  


}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

//flipscreen not loading again
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){        
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

// To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
/*@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
        web.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}*/
}
```

Comment: I hve tried ur code but still it's not working in my device. MyDevice's OS version is 4.4.2. I can see web page, but when I click on "Choose File" , nothing happens.

Comment: I am having the same issue. The API openFileChooser was removed from the KitKat webview.

Comment: @KushPatel I am facing this issue also. do you have any sol?

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
// Work on Android 4.4.2 Zenfone 5
public void showFileChooser(ValueCallback<String[]> filePathCallback,
            String acceptType, boolean paramBoolean){
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

and...

```
public void showFileChooser(ValueCallback<String[]> uploadFileCallback,
        FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
link : http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/android_webview/java/src/org/chromium/android_webview/AwContentsClient.java
```

I hope this helpful to you!

Comment: can you paste the full code, instead of //TODO Auto-generated method stub, please?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this code! Really long looked up for this!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that in Android 4.4 the file input is not implemented and it will never work through the standard WebView interface.
What I did in my project has been to use CrossWalk project to make it work fine.
It has required quite a bit of work to change the default WebView from the standard Android one to CrossWalk, however it really served my needs quite well.

Basically you need to replace the normal Android WebView with the CrossWalk webView. This had few advantages for us, including the fact that Chrome will be updated even on Android 4.0, 4.1 etc, giving us a much better support and fewer bugs.

I documented how I implemented it here: http://blog.maurizionapoleoni.com/blog/implementing-a-file-input-with-camera-support-in-android-with-crosswalk/

Comment: John the documented  link you shared is not working. I really want to see how you did it as I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Finally !! Yeaaaa.. Thank you John

Answer (score 0):

This code is running fine on my side.

```
 private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    //The undocumented magic method override
    //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here


    // For Android 3.0+
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("*/*");
        MainActivity1.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
    }

    //For Android 4.1+ only
    protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture)
    {
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
    }

    protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg)
    {
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
    }

    // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
        if (uploadMessage != null) {
            uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
            uploadMessage = null;
        }

        uploadMessage = filePathCallback;
        Intent intent = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
        }
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            uploadMessage = null;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Open File Chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Hope it will work for you...