# Is it possible to power an android webview with FireFox for android opensource code?

Tags: android, firefox, android-webview

I created an android webview for my website all was going fine only for me to notice that filechooser was not opening in android versions less than 5.0... After struggling for days, and trying so many things like solutions to SO questions [28600165](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28600165/cant-open-file-chooser-in-webview-android-4-4-2-using-webchromeclient) and [23568792](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28600165/cant-open-file-chooser-in-webview-android-4-4-2-using-webchromeclient) many other bunch of stuff online... nothing worked out(I bet you all of them are a waste of time). I later found it's a bug in older android versions and there's no real workaround like in this github issue [No workaround for filechooser bug for  4.4.1 and 4.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28600165/cant-open-file-chooser-in-webview-android-4-4-2-using-webchromeclient)  ... But I am able to upload files on all android versions using FireFox for android even Chrome... How come the HTML input type file works with FireFox webviews despite the bug in these particular versions of android... Is it possible for me to power my webviews with FireFox code since it's opensource if yes how easy is that and how effective will it be.... I will also appreciate guidelines on how to go about this, with an example if possible . thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure about firefox but you can try Crosswalk embedding API for android. https://crosswalk-project.org/ --- https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/apis/embedding_api.html

Comment: @Tasos thanks let me check that out.

Comment: Skip what they say in the installation part here https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android/embedding_crosswalk.html -- you can add dependency in the Gradle  -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781803/embed-crosswalk-in-android-studio -- change the version numbers to the latest -- curent ( 20.50.533.12 )  -- https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/downloads.php -- go back to the get started guide here   https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android/embedding_crosswalk.html -- carry on from step ( Add code to integrate the webview ) -- you be up and running in 5 minutes

Comment: Hello @Tasos I ran into problems with the File picker of crosswalk still the issue reported https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-2972 and a fix here https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk/pull/2647 but the fix was rejected though it works I want to apply the fix personally for my project any ideas on that? thanks for your support...

Comment: what files are you trying to access??

Comment: Trying to upload images, the file chooser opens on some devices but no uploads happens, after file is selected nothing actually happens

Comment: Maybe you need to try  Cordova then , because that exposes the android API's to do the work Natively rather than browser inbuilt API's. check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APGeUO4tAXg

Comment: This video better explains it Using Cordova  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EjXEfTMHp0

Comment: Ok, thanks, I tried cordova but it did work normally with java code, needed me to write some javascript(Meaning I have to modify my remotes site javascript), I already have a remote website all I need is a mobile app that allows the upload button work...

Comment: If you cant find a solution then you need to write Native code to handle the Uploads and use the Android Webview -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126625/how-do-i-send-a-file-in-android-from-a-mobile-device-to-server-using-http

Comment: Mozilla is currently working on this but they don't consider it ready yet https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView