# How to access internal storage while uploading image from webview?

Tags: android, webview, image-uploading

I have an app in which I am using WebView, If user wants to upload picture i want to show him internal storage options as we see in google chrome, as shown in image[image]

Here is the code that I am using :

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
            if (null == mUploadMessage)
                return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                    : intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;

        }
    }

    class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        @Override
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
           openFileChooser();

            return true;
        }

        // The undocumented magic method override
        // Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here
        public void openFileChooser() {

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image");
            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Browser"),
                    FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried replacing `i.setType("image");` with `i.setType("*/*");` ?

Comment: i.setType("image/*"); this worked for me, thanks for your efforts

Comment: Test this in device having android 4.4.2 OS. If it doesn't work then try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28600165/cant-open-file-chooser-in-webview-android-4-4-2-using-webchromeclient this.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to open file chooser.

```
/**
     * Get the Intent for selecting content to be used in an Intent Chooser.
     *
     * @return The intent for opening a file with Intent.createChooser()
     * 
     */
    public static Intent createGetContentIntent() {
        // Implicitly allow the user to select a particular kind of data
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        // The MIME data type filter
        intent.setType("*/*");
        // Only return URIs that can be opened with ContentResolver
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        return intent;
    }
```