# Webview HTML input type file in Android

Tags: android, webview

I tried lots of methods to upload a file in android webview, but i couldn't.
Also i tried belove link.

[HTML file input in android webview (android 4.4, kitkat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882331/html-file-input-in-android-webview-android-4-4-kitkat)

**http://www.apexkomenerji.com/m/teklifal.aspx** is my link.

Can someone give me a basic sample for all Android versions. (lollipop, kitkat etc.)

Here is my MainActivity:

```
package com.hemoliz;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import com.hemoliz.R;

import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView wv;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ImageButton news,forum,msg,acc;

    public void onBackPressed (){

        if (wv.isFocused() && wv.canGoBack()) {
                wv.goBack();       
        }
        else {
            openMyDialog(null);
        }
    }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Uygulamamızı tam ekran yapmak için alttaki kodları ekliyoruz
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
if(internetAccess()){

{

//İNTERNET ERİŞİMİ VARSA YAPILACAK İŞLEMLER
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.tarayici);
    wv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    wv.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    wv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
        }
    });
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);



    mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Yükleniyor",
            "İçerik Yüklenirken Lütfen Bekleyiniz.");
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            view.loadUrl(url); //
            return true;
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

    }); // linkleri uygulama içinde açar.

    try {
        // load the url
        wv.loadUrl("http://www.apexkomenerji.com/m/teklifal.aspx");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // uygulamanın açmasını istediğimiz sayfa.
}

}else{

{

//İNTERNET ERİŞİMİ YOKSA YAPILACAK İŞLEMLER
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet Bağlantınızı Kontrol Ediniz, Uygulama Kapanacaktır.",
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Timer t = new Timer();
     t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                    // This will kill your app after 5 seconds...
            }
     }, 5000);
}

}


}

public boolean internetAccess(){
     ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService (Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);    
     if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null

                && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()

                && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {

                return true;

                }  else {

                    return false;

                    }
}

public void openMyDialog(View view) {
    showDialog(10);
}
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 10:
        // Create our AlertDialog
        Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Çıkmak İstediğinizden Emin Misiniz ?")
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton("Evet",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                // Ends the activity
                                MainActivity.this.finish();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Hayır",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {

                            }
                        });

        return builder.create();


    }
    return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}


}
```

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15423907/4428462).

Comment: @JonasCz i also tried this. for 4.4 and lollipop didnt work.

Comment: See [here](https://gauntface.com/blog/2014/10/17/what-you-need-to-know-about-the-webview-in-l) for Lollipop. File upload not possible in 4.4 unless you use a third party WebView Replacement.

Comment: is this just for lollipop or for all versions except 4.4?

Comment: Just for lollipop, although you can combine it with my first link to support every version except 4.4.