# file input - accept image from camera or gallery on android

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, html-input

I have Form in my website that accepts a file input. the code for the input is here:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture/>
```

When I run this on my note 4 with google chrome for android I get to choose only Camera apps to add the image from. I cannot choose to use image from gallery or photos.

In IPhone with Safari it works perfect. it allows me to choose from gallery or camera. what not in google chrome for android? what am i missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Android 4.4 (Kit Kat) then this is a known issue:
[Issue 62220](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220)

You can follow the suggested work arounds: [HTML file input in android webview (android 4.4, kitkat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882331/html-file-input-in-android-webview-android-4-4-kitkat)